# How to lower a files length by chopping off its beginning rather than the end part?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-mapped-files

I've been using SetFilePointer/SetEndOfFile to manage the size of the memory mapped files I got. I've had a bunch of trouble with windows filesystem responding to the rapid changes I sometimes need to make but I think I finally got a hang of it.

Currently it seems like the best solution would be to make a new file each time I need to grow/shrink my data (it needs to temporarily coexist with the old file) but another potential solution would be if I could extend the file and after the old section loses its significance just cut it out. That would make it all neat and tidy.

I couldn't find any reference as to how I could actually do it though. Also would it be possible to preserve the map views (pointing to the same new part despite their actual position in regards to file start being different) throughout the resizing effort?

Comment: Mayme... Extend the length of the existing file when necessary. Store an offset in the header of the existing file pointing to the start of valid date. Optimize when necessary.

Comment: I stumbled on an interesting article - http://www.flexhex.com/docs/articles/sparse-files.phtml